# Android my class in not onCreate() method. but exception System services not available to Activities before onCreate()

Tags: java, android

recently I work A.class in coding.

I know why show this exception.
but my class not onCreate() method 
A class extends BaseContent 
basecontent is abstract class.

basecontent not onCreate() method.

how can I processor ?

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
```

Here's the code:

```
 private OnClickListener mConnectOnClick = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


        final WifiConfiguration config = Wifi.getWifiConfiguration(mWifiManager, mScanResult, mScanResultSecurity);
        boolean connResult = false;

        if (config != null) {
                            connResult = Wifi.connectToConfiguredNetwork(mFloating, mWifiManager, config, false);   //WI-FI connect
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(v.getContext());
            dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

            dialog.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE);
            dialog.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
            dialog.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // hide nav bar
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // hide status bar
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
            dialog.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE);





            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            int m_iNetworkType = (activeNetwork == null) ? -1 : activeNetwork.getType();


                dialog.dismiss();
            }
            else {
                dialog.show();
            }
        }
        if (!connResult) {
            Toast.makeText(mFloating, R.string.toastFailed, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

};
```

Here's the exception:

```
: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: kr.co.iosystem.wificonnecter, PID: 4521
java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
  at android.app.Activity.getSystemService(Activity.java:4532)
  at kr.co.iosystem.wificonnecter.connecter.ConfiguredNetworkContent$1.onClick(ConfiguredNetworkContent.java:263)
  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please post the stack trace for the exception and show the part of your code that throws the exception (including enough surrounding code to provide meaningful context for the call).

Comment: @TedHopp   sorry..  edit question.

Comment: Is `ConfigureNetworkContent` an `Activity` subclass? How is this `onClick()` method getting called?

Comment: @Ted Hopp thanks,  where is `ConfigureNetworkContent` ?   mConnectOnClick getting called .     `@Override
    public OnClickListener getButtonOnClickListener(int index) {
        switch (index) {
            case 0:
                return mConnectOnClick;
            case 1:
                return mCancelOnClick;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
`'

Comment: `getButtonOnClickListener` is     button listener get

Comment: From your heading I think you are not calling onCreate method. You have to call onCreate() method first.

Comment: @mubeen I agree you . I try my class `@Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       }`     but same exception

Comment: The stack trace indicates that your code is inside a class named `ConfigureNetworkContent`. I still don't understand how your code is getting executed. The code you posted in the comment does not _execute_ `mConnectOnClick.onClick(view)`; it just returns the listener itself. Are you clicking on a button?

Comment: @TedHopp yes,  I made custom dialog, if dialog click, wifi connect.

Comment: perhaps add information. advice for me thank :)

Comment: You need to display the dialog from within an activity that has been created. From the exception stack trace, it appears that this is not happening. Without seeing more code (specifically, how the dialog is being constructed and displayed), it's hard to say how you should fix this.